# CSS - Vertically centered div ignores parent padding-bottom

Tags: css

Here is my example: http://torjinx.me

If you click on the mail icon, a modal opens. The modal has `padding: 41px 0;` applied to it. However, if the height of the viewport is less than the height of the contact form, the modal's `padding-bottom` is ignored, and the Send/Reset buttons are right up against the bottom of the viewport.

How can I get some space between those buttons and the bottom of the viewport?

HTML:

```
<div id="modal">
   <div id="contact-form">
      <form>
         <input type="text" />
         <input type="text" />
         <textarea></textarea>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#modal {
    padding: 41px 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 350ms, visibility 350ms;
    transition: opacity 350ms, visibility 350ms;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
#contact-form {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: The `padding-bottom` is not being ignored. What's happening is that the elements inside the form are overflowing the container. Add `overflow: auto` to `#contact-form`.

Comment: Post your relevant HTML/CSS here. Don't just link to your website.

Comment: @Michael_B I tried that, but it added a new scrollbar next to the contact form and looks very silly!

Comment: Yikes. Have you ever done web design before? What do you think is going to happen if there's too much content for the height of the viewport?

Comment: @Josh Crozier I've added the relevant HTML/CSS to my question. Are there any other guidelines I should follow when asking a question here?

Comment: Why are you doing both `top: 50%` and `transform: translateY(-50%)`? They're cancelling each other out.

Comment: @JakeParis Yes, tons. I think that normally the content wouldn't ignore the parent's padding, regardless of whether it extends beyond the viewport. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @JakeParis No, they aren't. I'm using this method of vertically centering content within a container: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

I've used it many times without issues but this seems to be a unique situation.

Comment: @torjinx - No, that's good. Typically you just need to post the relevant or problematic code in question. In doing so, your question will still be useful when your website changes or when links break.

Comment: @JakeParis I think you are completely misunderstanding my question. I don't want to force the content to get smaller. I just want it to honor its parent's padding-bottom when it's extending beyond the viewport - but it isn't.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Ok, I apologize, I did misunderstand your question. I see what you mean now.

Comment: Just put `margin-bottom` on your `#contact-form`

Comment: @torjinx, I didn't necessarily mean for you to use the scrollbar in the final layout. It was just a way to illustrate the problem. You could also have added a border around the element to see what's happening.

Comment: @Michael_B Hmm, I see what you mean now. So I guess the question is, why isn't the `#contact-form` container expanding to fit its contents?

Comment: Because you have it limited with a `max-height: 100%`.

Comment: @Michael_B Ah I see. But if I take that away, the vertical centering no longer works when the viewport is shorter than the `#contact-form`. Perhaps I need to use a different vertical centering method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a hack to make my already-hacky vertical centering work without flexbox! All I had to do was wrap `#contact-form` in `<table><tr><td>`. Then I added `padding: 22px 0;` to the `td`. Presumably this works because tables take up space even if they stretch beyond their container.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here would be to remove the hacky `translateY(-50%)/top:50%` stuff from the inner element and let flexbox do the work for you. Add this to the outer element instead:

```
#contact {
   -webkit-display: flex;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

That will center the inner element both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Thank you, I would really love to use flexbox here but I'd rather make something that vertically centers on older browsers too. Mostly I just want to know if it can be done. If not, what I currently have will be the fallback and I will use flexbox.

Comment: I kind of understand, but flexbox is pretty standard these days: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox  How many old browsers do you really need to support?

Comment: It depends on who I'm doing a website for. In this case it may not matter but in some of my contracts it does. The top answers here explain what I mean very well: https://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/3zbd4p/is_it_safe_to_use_flexbox_yet/

That being said, it appears I may not be able to make a better fallback than what I have. If that's the case yours will be the answer I pick. :)

Comment: Sure, I get that. Keep in mind that Reddit post is a year old, which is about a million years in web design.

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't take the padding into account when calculating at the scroll.

If your modal is 100% of the viewport height and the inner element is longer than that, padding on the bottom to the modal element will not give extra space at the bottom. Instead, add a margin to the *inner* element, and that will push down your scroll, and give you the padding you want at the bottom.

So, if you look at this example, you can see that the bottom margin of the inner element gives you space at the bottom. If you take away that bottom margin and put some bottom padding on the modal (outer) element, you get no space at the bottom.

```css
body, html { margin: 0;padding: 0; }
.modal {
   height: 90vh;
   margin: 5px auto;
   background: silver;
   overflow: scroll;
 }
 
 .inner {
    height: 150%;
    width: 75px;
    background: green;
    margin: 2em;
   }
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="inner">Hiya</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that but it doesn't make any difference. :(

Comment: Hm. I just did it on your website and it seemed to solve it. Really, so you added `margin-bottom: 140px` to the #content-form element?

Comment: Yes, but I used 40px. You are onto something though. As @Michael_B pointed out, the `#contact-form` container is not expanding to fit its contents. Adding the 140px margin makes it expand just enough to appear as though it's fitting to the contents, but really it's not.

Comment: @torjinx Part of the problem is the `max-height: 100%` on the `#contact-form` element. Take that off and you can see that the outer element now wraps all the way around it's children.

Comment: yes but if I remove that, the vertical centering no longer works (when the viewport is shorter than the `#contact-form`).